# Como comparar respostas e gabaritos sendo que cada um é uma string PHP

Tags: php, array, string, foreach

Tenho 2 strings em PHP que são as respostas do aluno e o gabarito. Preciso compará-las e mostrar o  resultado em uma tabela:

```
$respostas='1;A|2;B|3;C';
$gabaritos='1;A|2;B|3;D';
```

Preciso que ele gere no final uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
Pergunta | Resposta | Gabarito
   1     |    A     |    A
   2     |    B     |    B
   3     |    C     |    D
```

Fiz um explode para separar as perguntas, depois um foreach para trazer cada resultado e depois outro explode para separar as perguntas e repostas para montar a tabela das repostas, mas não sei como incluir o gabarito dentro dessa tabela:

```
$gbarray = explode('|',$respostas);
foreach($gbarray as $resposta){
        $questoes = explode(';',$resposta);
        $questao = $questoes [0];
        $resposta = $questoes [1];
echo '
      <tr>
            <td>Matéria</td>
            <td>'.$questao.'</td>
            <td>'.$resposta.'</td>
            <td>Reposta Gabarito</td>
            <td>Pontuação</td>
            <td>% Acerto dos Membros</td>
      </tr>
}
```

Comment: Pesquise o que a função `array_map` faz quando você define o primeiro parâmetro como NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sintaxe:

```
foreach($rparray as $key => $resposta){
            ↑        ↑           ↑
          array    índice      valor
```

Depois basta fazer um explode nos itens de `$gbarray` usando como índice o valor de `$key`. Abaixo eu renomeei as variáveis para efeito de organização:

```
<?
$respostas='1;A|2;B|3;C';
$gabaritos='1;A|2;B|3;D';

$rparray = explode('|',$respostas);
$gbarray = explode('|',$gabaritos);

echo '<table>';

foreach($rparray as $key => $resposta){
        $questoes = explode(';',$resposta);
        $gabaritos = explode(';',$gbarray[$key]);
        $questao = $questoes [0];
        $resposta = $questoes [1];
        $gabarito = $gabaritos[1];
echo '
      <tr>
            <td>Matéria</td>
            <td>'.$questao.'</td>
            <td>'.$resposta.'</td>
            <td>'.$gabarito.'</td>
            <td>Pontuação</td>
            <td>% Acerto dos Membros</td>
      </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/l4PObg)**

Comment: Deu certo, valeu!